# OrientDB: UPDATE of adjacent vertex

Tags: orientdb

### Background

I have a model represented by a graph in OrientDB. The model consists of a few classes, among others `A` and `B`. The classes are connected with a relation `has` as an edge from `A` to `B`. The edge also connects `A` to other classes:

```
A ---has--> B
A ---has--> C
```

### Problem

I want to update a property of `B` if it has a `has` edge to an `A` with a given RecordID.

### My Solution

Currently I am selecting the target/out vertex of all edges `has` that are of class `B` starting at a given RecordID. This works but feels like I am missing an easier solution to this.

`UPDATE (SELECT expand(out('has')[@class = 'B']) FROM #11:1) SET prop = true`

I also tried the following, which did **not** work as I expected:

`UPDATE B SET prop = true WHERE in('has').@rid = #11:1`

### My Question

Is there a simpler solution than an UPDATE with SUBSELECT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any premade sql function that does this kind of filtering in an [update](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Update.html).

Your first query is the  way to go because it traverses instead of filtering on all the vertices. Yes, you have a subquery but it is faster then using a where in the update statement.

It would be cool to have a syntax like this :

```
update #9:1.inV('edgeClassName')[@class='className'] set prop = true
```

We have to use a subquery for this to work. It feels natural to me.